# Return positive value always even if it is negative

Tags: php, mysql

```
select c.firstname,c.lastname,s.salesprice,p.recommendedprice,s.salesprice - p.recommendedprice as 
from customers as c inner join sales as s
on c.customerid=s.customerid inner join products as p
on s.productid=p.productid
```

I know maths has a function for this but i don't know which specific function to use in mysql.

I have difference table which needs to be returned as always positive.

for example:  difference is -50 and i want +50 in column.

Comment: Mysql has an abs() function.

Comment: how to use abs() in mysql ?

Comment: ok it works...thanks...i thought there will be something else...abs() also works in c# ? so..

Comment: 'As'? As what exactly??

Comment: sorryy...that was typing mistake !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your query `s.salesprice - p.recommendedprice` is calculating the price that has to be refunded. So just put `ABS` before the calculation. like the below query

```
select c.firstname,c.lastname,s.salesprice,p.recommendedprice,ABS(s.salesprice - p.recommendedprice) as 
from customers as c inner join sales as s
on c.customerid=s.customerid inner join products as p
on s.productid=p.productid
```

for more [information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs)

Comment: @MehulSolanki : what do you want to know about nested queries?

Comment: just explain the simple michanism so i can understand and use it @urfusion

Comment: @MehulSolanki : think this might help you. http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/subqueries/index.php